# How to download lex and lex.yy.c and yacc in ubuntu9.10?

Tags: linux

How to download lex and lex.yy.c and yacc in ubuntu9.10 ?

Comment: Haha, don't think you don't get enough attention on Stack Overflow

Comment: Are you trying to download it once, twice, or three times?

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo apt-get install flex bison
```

`lex.yy.c` will be generated by flex.

Answer (score 0):

Lex and yacc (as such) are basically obsolete. You probably want [Flex](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/flex.htm) and [byacc](http://invisible-island.net/byacc/byacc.html). lex.yy.c is a file created by [F]lex based on the lexer specification you input.